# Django use model manager method after filter()

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm using `Django 2.2`

I have a **Video** model with custom methods defined in the model manager

```
class VideoManager(models.Manager):
    def completed(self):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(status=self.model.STATUS_POST_COMPLETE)


class Video(models.Model):
    STATUS_UPLOADED = 'uploaded'
    STATUS_POST_COMPLETE = 'post_complete'

    STATUSES = (
        (STATUS_UPLOADED, 'Uploaded'),
        (STATUS_POST_COMPLETE, 'Post Complete'),
    )

    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to=user_upload_directory_path)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUSES, default=STATUS_UPLOADED, blank=True, max_length=50)

    objects = VideoManager()
```

In the view file, I want to get count of completed video

```
class VideoListView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'videos/list.html'
    model = Video

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(campaign__user=self.request.user)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        stats = {
            'total': self.get_queryset().count(),
            'completed': self.get_queryset().completed().count()
        }
        context['stats'] = stats

        return context
```

I'm using `self.get_queryset()` to get already filtered for user and then get all completed videos using model manager method.

I followed this approach to reduce repeated variables.

But this gives error

```
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'completed'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `completed()` is `Manager` method and not `QuerySet` method. You need to implement Custom `QuerySet` also. `Manager` methods are not chainable. You can not use `Manager` method again after `QuerySet` will be returned. Methods like (`all()`, `filter()`, `annotate()`, `exclude()`), They are both implemented on `Manager` level as well as on `QuerySet` level.

See this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#calling-custom-queryset-methods-from-the-manager).

## models.py

```
class VideoQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def completed(self):
        return self.filter(status=self.model.STATUS_POST_COMPLETE)

class VideoManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return VideoQuerySet(model=self.model, using=self._db)

    def completed(self):
        return self.get_queryset().completed()

class Video(models.Model):
    STATUS_UPLOADED = 'uploaded'
    STATUS_POST_COMPLETE = 'post_complete'

    STATUSES = (
        (STATUS_UPLOADED, 'Uploaded'),
        (STATUS_POST_COMPLETE, 'Post Complete'),
    )

    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to=user_upload_directory_path)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUSES, default=STATUS_UPLOADED, blank=True, max_length=50)

    objects = VideoManager()

video_qs = Video.objects.filter(**lookup_kwargs).completed()
# or
video_qs = Video.objects.completed()
```

As you want. I hope I do not have a mistake.

Comment: What could be the best approach for the above scenario. Can you share an example of the best implementation?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation they linked to. You'll see the difference in the QuerySet subclass and the manager Subclass. You need to switch away from the Manager to the QuerySet approach.